# Having problem in accessing json "%" named variable data in ionic 4

Tags: json, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

My JSON data is like:

```
{
  %: 0,
  Absent: 1,
  Month: "May 2019",
  Present: 0
}
```

and i want access % data in my code but its giving me error,

i have tried e.g :

```
i.%
```

like normal access of json data

```
<ion-row class="row2" *ngFor='let i of mainData'>
  <ion-col>
    <div class="col-1 div-font">{{i.Month}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <div class="div-font">{{i.Present}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col>
    <div class="div-font">{{i.Absent}}</div>
  </ion-col>
  <ion-col size="2.5">
    <div class="div-font">{{i.%}}</div>
  </ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

**This is error i m getting**

[image: This is error i m getting]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access any property if you use `obj['prop']` instead of `obj.prop`, although this kinda goes against type safety/pattern matching, and will mean that if you change a property later on (say `%` to `percent`), you will manually have to change every `obj['%']` to `obj.percent` (or `obj['percent']` but please dont).

I would recommend changing your JSON response to have `%` be another property name instead, something that doesn't include special character if possible.

If you can't change it or really want to stick with it just use:

```html
<div class="div-font">{{i['%']}}</div>
```

instead.

Comment: Thanks brother its working now , you saved life! :)